# Error: Constructor does not have return type and it says that variables x and y are undeclared

Tags: c++, templates

I have to create a template for two points (`x` and `y`). The compiler says that the variables are "undeclared identifiers" and I don't know why, but I already declared them in the constructor!!

I also get an error about the constructor not having a return type.  What does that mean?

How can I fix these errors?

**This is header code**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

template <typename T>

class Point{

  private:

    T x;
    T y;

  public :

    Point(T x, T y);
    T getX();
    T getY();
    void setX(T xcoord);
    void setY(T ycoord);
    void print();
};

#endif

template <typename T>
T Point<T> :: Point(T x, T y){
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
}

template <typename T>
T Point<T> :: getX() {
  return x;
}

template <typename T>
T Point<T> :: getY(){
  return y;
}

template <typename T>
void T Point<T> :: setX( T xcoord){
  x = xcoord;
}
```

This is the main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  Point<int> p1(3,5);
  p1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

**Note that the code in the main file was commented out when the console was ran. These errors come only from the header file**

Errors:

> Variable T from setx constructor has incomplete type <void> , expected ";"
>
> unknown type "T"
>
> extra member qualification on member "setx"
>
> undeclared use of identifier "x"

[image]

Comment: Why is your #endif in the middle of your file?

Comment: It's all in one file. My professor wrote this code fyi, so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: This was a single file that your prof gave you? Did they say it's supposed to compile?

Comment: Is that homework and the task is to figure out the errors and fix them?

Comment: "I have to create a template for two pointers". Hmm, looks more like this is about points, not pointers.... Or maybe about math vectors (in contrast to C++ vectors).

Comment: Please state what kind of file the shown code is in. Is it a header or a code file?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean points. No, this is supposed to work. There is another main file that tests the class, should I include it?

Comment: This is header code

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Maybe that is all the code you have and if you compile it (assuming it is a code file, which I kind of doubt) you get the errors you describe. But for an MRE, you need to provide the error messages you get, in full, as text, directly here, verbatim and with the lines which cause them identified in your shown code.

Comment: Yes please, show the code you compile to provoke the described errors. Also please describe/quote what exactly it is you are supposed to do. Currently it seems that @Shadow is most plausibly guessing.

Comment: Was there anythign unclear about "**as text**, directly here"? Please not (or at least not only) as a picture. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Okay I will fix it

Comment: If you get multiple errors, always start to fix the first one first. The later errors much too often are caused by the compiler misunderstanding everything after the first error. The error you describe are irrelevant.

Comment: For fixing the first error you need to decide whether you want a return value of type `void` (i.e. no return value) or of type `T`. For a setter method, I think void is appropriate, so simply delete the `T`, which matches the declaration inside the class.

Comment: If that is really the unmodified code you were given and it really is supposed to work without any modifications I hope the prof just had a really bad day. Otherwise I would recommend to avoid him and his lectures in the future as much as possible.

Comment: That worked, I really appreciate your help. How would I code the constructor given the code?

Comment: The error you quote as text does not occur in your picture AND does not read like an error I would expect. The "setx constructor" alone is already implausible.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
T Point<T> :: Point(T x, T y){
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
}
```

should be (CORRECTED)

```
template <typename T>
Point<T> :: Point(T x, T y){
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
}
```

Constructors don't have return types (as the error says), and `xcoord` and `ycoord` are not members of your class.

also

```
template <typename T>
void T Point<T> :: setX( T xcoord) {
  x = xcoord;
}
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
void Point<T> :: setX( T xcoord) {
  x = xcoord;
}
```

`void T` is not a valid type.

Comment: When I make this fix, I am getting an error that tells me that xcoord and ycoord are undeclared identifiers.

Comment: Btw these were also a declaration-definition mismatches. So comparing the declarations and the definitions would have helped.

Comment: JOHN IT WORKED.THANK YOU SO MUCH GOD BLESS YOU :)))))))

Answer (score 0):

If you get multiple errors, always start to fix the first one first. The later errors much too often are caused by the compiler misunderstanding everything after the first error. The error you describe are irrelevant.

For fixing the first error you need to decide whether you want a return value of type void (i.e. no return value) or of type T. For a setter method, I think void is appropriate, so simply delete the T, which matches the declaration inside the class.

This (as you confirmed in a comment) fixes the first of the errors and because of the otherwise implausible  and inconsistent question I consider this to be the core of the question. Please create a new question on how to implement a constructor.